# initialize this buffer uint8*

Tags: c++, uint

I have this typedef

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;
```

and this variable

```
public : uint8* bufferOfExchange;
```

how could I initialize this buffer?

```
bufferOfExchange = ???
```

Comment: The answer to this depends on the value that you want it to have once initialised.

Comment: Maybe `new uint8` or `new uint8[size]` or maybe U don't really need pointer...

Comment: You could initialize it to null bufferOfExchange = 0; or you could allocate memory bufferOfExchange = (uint8*)malloc(1024); and so on

Comment: I dlike to  have something like byte[] from c# =). So c#(byte[])->c++(uint8* buffer)

Comment: @curiousity- In that case you should be using `std::vector<uint8>` instead of `uint8*`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
bufferOfExchange = new uint8[bufferSize]; //bufferSize is size_t type. 

//or
bufferOfExchange = otherBuffer; //otherBuffer is of same type
```

What else do you think?

Better choice would be to use `std::vector<uint8>` instead of `uint8*`:

```
std::vector<uint8> bufferOfExchange;
```

Now, read some good book to know how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: I dlike to have something like byte[] from c# =). So c#(byte[])->c++(uint8* buffer) is it possible?

Comment: @curiousity: I suggested you to use `std::vector<uint8>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't have a buffer, only an uninitialized pointer. You can create a buffer with new like this:

```
bufferOfExchange = new uint8[10];
```

(10 is an arbitrary choice - use the buffer size you need.)

For real code however, you would probably want `std::vector<uint8>`.